# Pandas efficiently normalize column titles in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to automatically read rows when loading in dataframe by automatically normalizing to one term. The following code works:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('Test.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", index_col=0)

firstCol=['FirstName','First Name','Nombre','NameFirst', 'Name', 'Given name', 'given name', 'Name']
df.rename(columns={typo: 'First_Name' for typo in firstCol}, inplace=True)

addressCol=['Residence','Primary Address', 'primary address' ]
df.rename(columns={typo: 'Address' for typo in addressCol}, inplace=True)

computerCol=['Laptop','Desktop', 'server', 'mobile' ]
df.rename(columns={typo: 'Address' for typo in computerCol}, inplace=True)
```

Is there a more efficient way of looping or rewriting it so it is less redundant?

Comment: I'd say not off the top of my head but won't this potentially introduce duplicate column names?

Comment: To get python3-specific answers, consider tagging your question(s) with `python3.x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to just reduce it to one `df.rename` op, by building a complete dictionary once off, eg:

```
replacements = {
    'Name': ['FirstName','First Name','Nombre','NameFirst', 'Name', 'Given name', 'given name', 'Name'],
    'Address': ['Residence','Primary Address', 'primary address' ],
    #...
}

df.rename(columns={el:k for k,v in replacements.iteritems() for el in v}, inplace=True)
```

So it *should* be more efficient as to function call overhead, but I'd personally view it as more readable by having a `dict` of keys, which are the "to" values, with the values being the "from"'s to replace.

Comment: Is this possible for python 3? I thought `.iteritems()` was deprecated and probably changed to `.items()` or am I wrong?

Comment: @ccsv it wasn't deprecated - it was just removed and replaced with `.items` which does the same thing now. Python 3.x has generally been made more lazy with stuff... so `dict.items()` is the 2.x equiv of `dict.iteritems()`...